# How to reuse an imageview in several layouts

Tags: android, imageview

Hey guys I have a few image views that I am using several times in multiple layouts in my activity. Is there any way to list the imageviews in a single .xml file and just reference them from all the layouts instead of retyping them each time?

Kind of like what you can do for strings. you can list them all in a strings.xml folder then just reference them to keep your code clean and so you can reuse the strings in several layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start here

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html

Comment: If I did that though, I would have to make seperate layouts for each textview. I don't want to include an entire layout, just single textviews. Also how would I get the imageviews to line up vertically? Would android know to put them in the order I code them in?

Comment: None of these concerns were voiced in your original question, which was pretty vague. For example, you never once metioned TextViews until this comment, how are those related to the ImageViews?